# Is there a list which describes which map features in OSM is displayed per each zoom level?

Tags: openstreetmap

I found [this list](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features) of map features but there is no indication when they are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The [OpenStreetMap website](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) does have a map key (accessible through the "i" icon on the right) that changes based on your current zoom level.

However, this list of features is incomplete. I believe the only reliable source of truth are the style files in the [openstreetmap-carto repository](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/48.4910/13.4106) (essentially the source code for the standard map style on osm.org). There, you'll find statements such as

```
  [feature = 'amenity_parking_space'][zoom >= 18] {
    line-width: 0.3;
    line-color: mix(@parking-outline, @parking, 50%);
  }
```

which tells you that individual parking spaces appear at zoom 18 and greater.